# Getting started with a custom function with Excel Add-Ins

Tags: excel-addins, custom-functions-excel

I followed this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/excel-custom-functions-quickstart?tabs=excel-windows

So far everything went fine. I can use the =CONTOSO.CLOCK and other example functions.
If I add a function to the functions.ts file, it rebuilds... but I can't use the custom function on the web in any way.

Somehow I'm missing how I can register this function and run it in Excel...
Other question is: How can I change the name of the namespace from CONTOSO in something else?

Regards, Peter

Answer (score 0):

Okay, a valid JSDoc was needed to work. After running a new build it worked out. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/custom-functions-json-autogeneration